# SpriteKit texture "scaling" different from one to another

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, textures, sprite

**Exact same texture, different results**

Here an `SKSpriteNode` and `SKShapeNode` are given the same texture, from a texture atlas.

The `SKSpriteNode` is on the right, and it does the right thing.

[image]

The `SKShapeNode` is on the left, and doing the wrong thing.

### **Please, what am I doing wrong?**

here's the code...

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


    let myTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "demoArt")
    let arrayOfFileNames = myTextureAtlas.textureNames
    let myTexture = myTextureAtlas.textureNamed(arrayOfFileNames.last!)

    let circleShape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 180)
    circleShape.fillColor = SKColor.white
    circleShape.fillTexture = myTexture
    circleShape.position = CGPoint(x: 256, y: 384)
    addChild(circleShape)

    let circleSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 320))
    circleSprite.texture = myTexture
    circleSprite.position = (CGPoint(x: 768, y: 384))
    addChild(circleSprite)

    print(myTexture)
```

---

The result of `print(myTexture)` is correct:

> `<SKTexture>` 'seven.png' (512 x 512)

If you want to test this out, here are the image files going into the "atlas"...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug (it was wanted as is) , `SKShapeNode` scales a fill texture by default, instead of repeating the pattern and you don't have a direct control on this scaling.

As explained to the [API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skshapenode) reference:

> **Shape nodes are useful for content that cannot be easily decomposed
>   into simple textured sprites**. Shape nodes are also very useful for
>   building and displaying debugging information on top of your game
>   content. However, the **SKSpriteNode** class offers higher performance
>   than this class, so use shape nodes sparingly.

Using `SKShapeNode` beyond from these dictates will needlessly cost performance and can produce visual defects.

Comment: Unfortunately SKShapeNode has a bad story, you can read something in this old but true article http://sartak.org/2014/03/skshapenode-you-are-dead-to-me.html

Comment: This is a great shame. Now I have to fight with understanding physics bitmasking just to do touch detection testing on a circle. Mind bending!

Comment: um, this is definitely a bug,  and we can recreate it by not using an atlas as the other answer suggests.  Plus your quote has nothing to do with this issue

Comment: @Knight0fDragon This is not a bug: simply you can't control directly SKShapeNode scaling because it's not permitted. About my quote explain for what SKShapeNode should be used according with Apple rules, not opinions..

Comment: You can't control the scaling on any texture in SpriteKit @Alessandrio, SKShapeNode is reading beyond the memory it is suppose to be reading,  this is a bug and can lead to problems in areas where the given texture is in the corner of an atlas

Comment: Your quote just mentions that SKShapeNode is resource intensive, so for performance, use it when you have to. E.G. 24 SKShapeNodes is a lot slower than 24 SKSpriteNodes. This has nothing to do with visual defects

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Obviusly you don't know UIGraphicsBeginImageContex/UIGraphicsEndImageContext , you can scale a SKTexture. The memory issues do not affect this question, you speak about other bugs.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano, UIGraphicsBeginImageContex is something completely different, and is not SpriteKit.  None of the features in sprite kit allow for different definitions of scaling.  In Sprite Kit, you only get stretch, that is it, and you can't even anchor the stretching like in OpenGL.  The memory bug IS this problem,  the fillTexture is broken so instead of scaling based on the SKTexture information, it is reading beyond the texture space, going into unknown territory. If your SKTexture is in the corner of an atlas, your results will be unpredictable.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano, I just reread your answer,  I think you got the question logic backwards, and maybe that is why you are misinformed. Confused is not looking for a repeating pattern,  he only wants one of the digit textures, but he is getting all other textures in the atlas, so instead of scaling the single digit, it is showing other textures that do not belong

Comment: @Knight0fDragon "repeating pattern" has nothing to do with this thread. People following too much the fashion to shout to the bug, I've a game in the store full of SKShapeNode, I've test it and it's acceptable. I've seen a couple of comments from you that discrediting my help and I do not like this behavior from you. Answers could be voted and commented but with respect for the work and the knowledge of the other. This is my last comment.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano because your help is wrong, and I am helping you post the correct answer. I am also trying to understand why you think you are right, which is a lot more respectful then what most people do. I only said repeating pattern because he has all his textures on his atlas showing and perhaps you think he wants that size with no scaling (which can only be done with a repeating pattern since we can't control texture coordinates)

Comment: It's only your opinion I think you're wrong but stop comments , if you want to downvote me as you did in this answer do it but stop to judge me. Next time use the answer method, don't flame all threads  because people don't read ALL the comments, skip directly to the right answer without reading your or my 1000 opinions (this don't follow the rules). Please next time post an answer and people judge your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented your code and used a different set of textures (letters instead of numbers) and I got the exact same behavior. I suspect that SKShapeNode implements its fillTexture differently than SKSpriteNode.

In my code below, I made four nodes. The top two circles are SKShapeNodes and the bottom two are SKSpriteNodes.

- top left SKShapeNode uses `SKTexture(imageNamed: "a.png")`
- top right SKShapeNode uses `myTexture`
- bottom left SKSpriteNode uses `myTexture`
- bottom right SKSpriteNode uses `SKTexture(imageNamed: "a.png")`

To work around your issue, instead of using the texture atlas, just use an individual SKTexture like the top left circle in my example.

Here is my GameScene.swift file:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let myTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "8bitfont")
        let arrayOfFileNames = myTextureAtlas.textureNames
        print(arrayOfFileNames)
        let myTexture = myTextureAtlas.textureNamed("a.png")

        // Top left circle
        let circleShape1 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 160)
        circleShape1.fillColor = SKColor.white
        circleShape1.fillTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "a.png")
        circleShape1.position = CGPoint(x: -180, y: 180)
        addChild(circleShape1)

        // Top right circle
        let circleShape2 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 160)
        circleShape2.fillColor = SKColor.white
        circleShape2.fillTexture = myTexture as SKTexture
        circleShape2.position = CGPoint(x: 180, y: 180)
        addChild(circleShape2)

        // Bottom left circle
        let circleSprite1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 320))
        circleSprite1.texture = myTexture
        circleSprite1.position = (CGPoint(x: -180, y: -180))
        addChild(circleSprite1)

        // Bottom right circle
        let circleSprite2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 320))
        circleSprite2.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "a.png")
        circleSprite2.position = (CGPoint(x: 180, y: -180))
        addChild(circleSprite2)

        print(myTexture)
    }
}
```

Here is the result I get:

[image: Result]

Here is the full project on github:

https://github.com/starkindustries/SKShapeNodeVsSKSpriteNode

Comment: Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: your trick doesn't work for me. It causes the app to "crash" into a paused state before showing anything, and touch on the screen then shows the two circles as per the original question. Oddly, I don't have any touch handlers in the scene, or on any objects.

Comment: Take a look at my project on Github and you'll see an example of what I'm about to explain: You'll need to add your number images to your project again. The images inside your atlas folder cannot be accessed using SKTexture(imageNamed: ). You'll see in my GitHub project, the "a.png" file exists as a resource outside of the .atlas folder. This allows it to be accessed by the SKTexture() function.

Comment: The entire point of this project structure is that I need texture atlases. I've set this up as a demo of that fact. Without texture atlases, the actual project/game becomes completely unwieldy.

Comment: which is not to say that I don't appreciate the effort to find this "work-around", it's just that I need texture atlases. There's going to be thousands of images in hundreds of groups.

Comment: @Confuses, extract the texture from the atlas, and use the `.cgImage` to create a new texture to get around this : `SKTexture(cgImage:textureFromAtlas.cgImage)`

Comment: @Confused,  why are you using an SKShapeNode anyway?  Doesn't seem needed